# Creating a monthly/yearly calendar image with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I started to make a calendar in Excel, but thought it might be easy to do in R instead. (Note: I'm aware of various heatmap calendar packages but I prefer to use `ggplot2`.) Ultimately I want to make a calendar that shows 12 months starting from a given date, with each month as a small box showing 4 or 5 weeks on the y-axis (week 1 at the top, week 4 or 5 at the bottom) and the days of the week (starting from Monday) along the x-axis.

I thought this would be a 15-minute job (create data for all months, format a bit using `reshape` then use `facet_wrap`) but ran into problems almost immediately as the plot below shows - the days of the month are not in order, although the days of the week seem okay. Ordering data in R is my nemesis; I really should get a handle on this. Anyway, the image below shows what I have so far and the code is below that. This is just a fun project, not urgent, but any help and/or embellishments welcome.

[image: calendar]

```
require(ggplot2)
require(scales)
require(lubridate)

date.start <- as.Date('2013-09-01')
date.end <- date.start + months(1)

mydf <- data.frame(mydate = seq(as.Date(date.start),
                       as.Date(date.end) - days(1),
                       by = 'day'))

mydf$month <- month(mydf$mydate)
mydf$week <- week(mydf$mydate)
mydf$day <- day(mydf$mydate)
mydf$dow <- as.factor(format(mydf$mydate, format = "%a"))
levels(mydf$dow) <- c('Mon','Tue','Wed','Thu','Fri','Sat','Sun')

ggplot(mydf, aes(x = dow, y = as.factor(week))) +
    geom_tile(colour = "black", fill = "white", label = mydf$day) +
    geom_text(label = mydf$day, size = 4, colour = "black") +
    scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0,0)) +
    theme(axis.ticks = element_blank()) +
    theme(axis.title.y = element_blank()) +
    theme(axis.title.x = element_blank()) +
    theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent"))+
    theme(legend.position = "none") +
    theme()
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22815688/calendar-time-series-with-r - something I had written around April 2014.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create the `week.f` column with levels in reverse order. We have used `"%U"` (assuming US convention but if you want the UK convention use `"%W"` and also change the order of the factor levels of `dow`).  Also we have allowed arbitrary date input calculating the start of the month and have simplified the `ggplot` call slightly.

```
library(ggplot2)

input <- as.Date("2013-09-11") # input date

st <- as.Date(cut(input, "month")) # calculate start of month
dates31 <- st + 0:30 # st and next 30 dates (31 in all)
dates <- dates31[months(dates31) == months(st)] # keep only dates in st's month

week.ch <- format(dates, "%U") # week numbers

mydf <- data.frame(
   day = as.numeric(format(dates, "%d")),
   week.f = factor(week.ch, rev(unique(week.ch))),
   dow = factor(format(dates, "%a"), c("Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"))
)

ggplot(mydf, aes(x = dow, y = week.f)) +
    geom_tile(colour = "black", fill = "white") +
    geom_text(label = mydf$day, size = 4) + 
    scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0,0)) +
    theme(axis.ticks = element_blank()) +
    theme(axis.title = element_blank()) +
    theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent"))+
    theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image]

By the way, there is a `cal` function in the TeachingDemos package that can construct a one month calendar using classic graphics.

Comment: Thanks - chosen as this was the answer that showed me how to order the days of the month (and weeks) from 1 to 31, top to bottom, but I learnt something from each answer.

Comment: Seems to work over year change +1, how can you color only certain tiles with different colors?

Comment: Replace `"white"` in `fill="white"` with a vector of `nrow(mydf)` elements specifying the colors to fill the tiles with.

Answer (score 6):

This line of your code is wrong:

```
levels(mydf$dow) <- c('Mon','Tue','Wed','Thu','Fri','Sat','Sun')
```

It is because `mydf$dow` is already a factor and by using `levels` you are just renaming current levels. In this case you are just renaming `"Fri" "Mon" "Sat" "Sun" "Thu" "Tue" "Wed"` to `'Mon','Tue','Wed','Thu','Fri','Sat','Sun'` and this will create mess you get at the end.

If you look at `mydf` in your example, you will see:

```
       mydate month week day dow
1  2013-09-01     9   35   1 Thu
2  2013-09-02     9   36   2 Tue
3  2013-09-03     9   36   3 Sat
4  2013-09-04     9   36   4 Sun
5  2013-09-05     9   36   5 Fri
6  2013-09-06     9   36   6 Mon
7  2013-09-07     9   36   7 Wed
```

Because of renaming, names of days do not match to dates anymore.

Once corrected, everything works as expected:

```
require(ggplot2)
require(scales)
require(lubridate)


date.start <- as.Date('2013-09-01')
date.end <- date.start + months(1)

mydf <- data.frame(mydate = seq(as.Date(date.start),
                                as.Date(date.end) - days(1),
                                by = 'day'))

mydf$month <- month(mydf$mydate)
mydf$week <- week(mydf$mydate)
mydf$day <- day(mydf$mydate)
mydf$dow <- as.factor(format(mydf$mydate, format = "%a"))

mydf$dow <- factor(mydf$dow, levels=c('Mon','Tue','Wed','Thu','Fri','Sat','Sun'))

ggplot(mydf, aes(x = dow, y = as.factor(week))) +
  geom_tile(colour = "black", fill = "white", label = mydf$day) +
  geom_text(label = mydf$day, size = 4, colour = "black") +
  scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0,0)) +
  theme(axis.ticks = element_blank()) +
  theme(axis.title.y = element_blank()) +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_blank()) +
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent"))+
  theme(legend.position = "none") +
  theme()
```

[image]

Comment: There is a bug in this code when you a year change, picture [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Wz3t.png).

Answer (score 4):

Here you go:

```
start <- as.Date("2013-09-1")
numdays <- 30

weeknum <- function(date){
  z <- as.Date(date, format="%Y-%m-%d")
  as.numeric( format(z-1, "%U"))
}


dates <- data.frame(date=seq(start, length.out=numdays, by="1 day"))
dates <- within(dates, {
  weeknum <- weeknum(date)
  month   <- format(date, "%m")
  weekday <- format(date, "%a")
  day     <- format(date, "%d")
})

dates$weekday <- factor(dates$weekday, levels=c("Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"))

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dates, aes(x=weekday, y=weeknum)) + 
  geom_tile(fill="blue", col="white") +
  geom_text(aes(label=day))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this. The `weeknum` function exists to generate week numbers for weeks starting on a Monday?

Comment: There is some problem in this calendar chart during the year change, picture [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v2cuQ.png).