# R: visualising calendar predictions with ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, charts, calendar

You have numeric predictions that you want to show on a calendar.

*How can you visualise predictions about calendar data in R with ggplot2?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I gather below some ideas, I haven't found any single general-purpose package for this yet.*

---

**General ideas to visualise calendar data in R**

1. Heatmap like green-red to illustrate large-small predictions
2. Star symbol on dates to show special days
3. Lines over days to show special long-term events
4. Chart fusion ideas [here](http://datavizcatalogue.com/blog/chart-combinations-visualizing-data-in-calendars/)

**ggplot2 solutions to visualise calendar data in R**

3. [Creating a monthly/yearly calendar image with ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18741858/creating-a-monthly-yearly-calendar-image-with-ggplot2)
4. Openair package [here](http://www.openair-project.org/Downloads/Default.aspx), article [here](https://helenajambor.wordpress.com/2018/01/14/visualize-calendar-data-in-r/) and referenced article [here](https://www.r-bloggers.com/ggplot2-time-series-heatmaps/) (used originally for air pollutation visualisation but works for calendar week visualisation)

[image]

5. Some heatmap showing the weekday status [here](https://www.r-bloggers.com/calendar-charts-with-googlevis/)

[image]

**Other questions on calendar data**

1. [Calendar Time Series with R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22815688/calendar-time-series-with-r)