# Drawing box around Calendar week using R graphics or ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, graphics, calendar

I am trying to edit a word document and insert a calendar with certain graphics edited. How can I do the following:

1. fill a calendar day with color?
2. draw a box around a selected week?

Below is the code to build a calender using the TeachingDemos package. I am open to using a different package like ggplot2 (referencing: [Creating a monthly/yearly calendar image with ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18741858/creating-a-monthly-yearly-calendar-image-with-ggplot2)). I've included an example with that one as well:

```
#using TeachingDemos-----------------------------------------
library(TeachingDemos)
red = "flagged"
yellow = "draw box \naround \nweek"

#calendar and variables
day = as.Date("2017-09-01")
year = as.numeric(substr(day,1,4))
month = months(day)
month_n= as.numeric(substr(day,6,7))
cal(month
    ,year) 
setday = cal(month_n,year)

#mark days 8 and 9 as flagged
for( i in 8:9) {
  setday(i)
  text(0.6,0.6, red)
}


#highlight 17:23
for( i in 17:23) {
  setday(i)
  text(0.6,0.6, yellow)
}
```

Below is using ggplot

```
library(ggplot2)

input <- as.Date("2017-09-11") # input date

st <- as.Date(cut(input, "month")) # calculate start of month
dates31 <- st + 0:30 # st and next 30 dates (31 in all)
dates <- dates31[months(dates31) == months(st)] # keep only dates in st's month

week.ch <- format(dates, "%U") # week numbers

mydf <- data.frame(
  day = as.numeric(format(dates, "%d")),
  week.f = factor(week.ch, rev(unique(week.ch))),
  dow = factor(format(dates, "%a"), c("Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"))
)

ggplot(mydf, aes(x = dow, y = week.f)) +
  geom_tile(colour = "black", fill = "white") +
  geom_text(label = mydf$day, size = 4) + 
  scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0,0)) +
  theme(axis.ticks = element_blank()) +
  theme(axis.title = element_blank()) +
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent"))+
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are some options for the TeachingDemos `cal` option.

To fill a day with color you can use the `rect` function:

```
for( i in 8:9) {
  setday(i)
  rect(-0.04,-0.04,1.04,1.04, col="#ff000066")
}
```

I used a transparent red color so that the day number would still show, but you could also fill with solid color then redraw the numbers:

```
for( i in 8:9) {
  setday(i)
  rect(-0.04,-0.04,1.04,1.04, col="red")
  text(0,1, i, adj=c(0,1))
}
```

You may also want to look at the help page for `rect` to see how to turn off, or change the color of the border, or set other options.  Using 0 and 1 instead of -0.04 and 1.04 will mostly fill the rectangle and give a different effect.

To draw the rectangle around a week (or other group) takes a few steps:

```
# find left coordinate in device units
setday(17)
left <- grconvertX(-0.04, from='user', to='ndc')

# switch to last day of week and find left value in user coords
setday(23)
newleft <- grconvertX(left, from='ndc', to='user')

# turn off clipping
par(xpd=NA)

# draw rectangle
rect(newleft, -0.04, 1.04, 1.04, border='blue', lwd=3)
```

You can increase the numerical values if you want to have the rectangle further out.